# 403 Connection to server has been lost Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, node.js, phpmyadmin

I host a site that frequently communicates with my database.
I used to be able to edit fields etc, in the browser, but now when the site has been up for some time and more users have joined, I can no longer use Phpmyadmin because of this error :

***"403 error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to the server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status."*** See image.

[Popup error Phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmw5v.png)

As of now, we have around 1K users, and around 10-20 people online at any given time.
This error was not present before and has started to show, now when we have more users.
What can I do to fix this error?

Config

```
Debian 10
Nginx
MariaDB (MySQL)
Phpmyadmin 
Php7.3
Nodejs
```

Whereas all should be the latest versions.

**Update**

This problem seems to be for specific row types.
As of now  we can change just about anything except for "Longtext" rows.

Comment: what kind of request invoking this error in the first place? why don't you log everything and see what is really happening?

Comment: With Nodejs I can do all the things I want with my Database. But simply editing a row in the browser throws me this error. I'm guessing there are either Phpmyadmin or Mysql logs stored on the server? Is that correct

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: Phpmyadmin version : 4.9.5deb2~bpo10+1 . I've looked at some logs but I have not found anything. Do you want me to look at some specific logs?